# Excel VBA - Go through range and copy each cell 9 times

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a spreadsheet with data as follows:

```
   G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD ... etc. 
2  1
3  2
4  4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
5  8 16 24 32 40
```

That is, G2 = 1, G3 = 1 ... M4 = 28 and so on...

What I need help with is going through this range, which can be dynamic as people are entering data into this range when they need to change stuff.  I need to iterate through the rows and then columns and, for each cell that has a value, I need to paste it into a different sheet in column D, 9 times for each cell.

That is, on the 2nd sheet, the data above would come across as:

```
Column
  D
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  4
  4
  .. etc...
```

How do I iterate through each row, and then each column and then for each cell that has a value, copy that 9 times into column D on another sheet, and then for the next cell with a value, copy that BELOW what was pasted and so on?

Comment: I think what could work for you is to copy your data to another hidden sheet. Then, you would add a button to confirm the change in a cell. The button would start a macro, which works with a double Loop and compare each cell with the cell on the second sheet. On an incident of difference, it would add your 9 times 1/2/3... and change the value in the second sheets. This is how I understood the question, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It assumes you want to go column by column iterating through all the populated cells in that column, repeating the value 9 times.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OutputRepeatedValues()

    Dim arr()
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const NUMOFTIMES As Long = 9
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range(.Range("G2"), .Range("G2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Value
    End With

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, output As String

    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)     '<== iterate rows with a column, column by column
        For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(j, i)) Then output = output & Replicate(arr(j, i), NUMOFTIMES, DELIMITER)
        Next j
    Next i

    output = Left$(output, Len(output) - 1)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(Len(output), 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(output, DELIMITER))

End Sub

'Adapted from @this  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159080/string-repeat-function-in-vba?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
Public Function Replicate(ByVal RepeatString As String, ByVal NUMOFTIMES As Long, Optional ByVal DELIMITER As String = ",")
    Dim s As String, c As Long, l As Long, i As Long
    l = Len(RepeatString) + 1
    c = l * NUMOFTIMES
    s = Space$(c)

    For i = 1 To c Step l
        Mid(s, i, l) = RepeatString & DELIMITER
    Next i

    Replicate = s
End Function
```

**Notes:**

1. Test dataset laid out as shown below

[image: Data set-up]

2. I assume that you want to work with what ever data is down or the right of `G2`, including `G2`. In order to do this I am using `SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` to find the last used cell. I then construct a range with `.Range(.Range("G2"), .Range("G2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))`, which in this case is `$G$2:$Q$5`, and read that into an array.
3. Assume that you indeed iterate rows with a column before moving onto next column as described in your question. I concatenate the populated cells values whilst at the same time calling the Replicate function described in 4).
4. I have hijacked, and adapted, a performant function by [@this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159080/string-repeat-function-in-vba?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), to handle the string repeat. I have added in an optional argument for delimiter. A delimiter is added so I can later split on this to write out the results to individual cells within the target worksheet.
5. I split the string, `output`, on the delimiter, this creates an array of the repeated values, which I transpose, so I can write out to a column in the target sheet.

**Example output:**

[image: Output]

Edit:

If instead you want to loop the rows, then columns, use with the above function the following instead:

```
Public Sub OutputRepeatedValues()

    Dim arr()
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const NUMOFTIMES As Long = 9
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range(.Range("G2"), .Range("G2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Value
    End With

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, output As String

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)     '<== iterate rows with a column, column by column
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(i, j)) Then output = output & Replicate(arr(i, j), NUMOFTIMES, DELIMITER)
        Next j
    Next i

    output = Left$(output, Len(output) - 1)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(Len(output), 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(output, DELIMITER))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  This works in that it goes through all rows/columns but the output is different than I was looking for.  Your code goes down row G and pastes values 9 times, then goes to column H (h2, h3, etc), pastes those 9 times and so on.  I need it to go across each row, starting on row 2, if there were number in columns G, H, and I, I want it to paste G2 9 times on a different sheet, then H2, then I2, etc until no values, then go down to row 3 and do the same thing: find all cells with values and then one column at a time (G3, H3, I3, J3, and etc) transpose those values into one column.

Comment: Swop the loop round. Please see edit and let me know if works.

Comment: QHarr, you're a genius!  Thank you for this!  I'm currently studying your code so I can understand fully how it works.  Thank you for saving me so much of a headache!

Comment: No worries. If you need anything clarified please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My vba is rusty but I think this (pseudo) code might help you.

```
def last_row as integer, last_col as integer, row as integer, col as integer, target as integer
'I like something like this to get the value but you have to know the largest column: Cells(Rows.Count, col_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

target = 1

for col = 7 to last_col '7 = G
  for row = 2 to last_row
    if(Not IsEmpty(Cells(row,col)) then
      Range(Cells(target*9-8, 4), Cells(target*9, 4))= Cells(row,col)
      target = target +1
    end
  next row
next col
```

this iterates through all cols and rows checks if there is a value and the copies it to a 9-cell range then iterates the target so it will point to the next 9 cells.